# issue in sonar-project.properties file

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am working on Java.Sonar server,sonar-runner is working fine for me.

Here is my `sonar-project.properties` file.

```
   # Root project information
   sonar.projectKey=Sonar:ProjectKey
   sonar.projectName=ProjectName
   sonar.projectVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
   # Some properties that will be inherited by the modules   
   sonar.sources=/root/helios/ProjectName/src
   # Redefine properties
   # Note that you do not need to prefix the property here
   #sonar.projectName=Module 2
   # Comma-separated paths to test source directories (optional)
   sonar.tests=/root/helios/ProjectName/test
   #The value of the property must be the key of the language.
   sonar.language=java
```

When I run sonar-server, `http://localhost:9000/` then it is showing classes under source directory but it is not showing classes under test directory.

Please guide me,how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is currently no direct way to access to the unit test source files, for instance from the "Components" page, see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4036. For the time being, the only way to access to a unit test source file is by clicking on the number of unit test from a project dashboard but this requires to import a unit text execution report.